# how to close button create in images?

Tags: jquery, html, popup

Popup image is working but the close button is not closing the popup. What do i need to do for the close button to work?

html

-----popimages--in--html--

```
<a class='popupimage' href='assets/images/IMG-20190416-WA0000.jpg' href="#1531375042863-9c2074c8-cca9" data-vc-tabs data-vc-container=".vc_tta" class="link-block"></a>
```

-------js--

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(.'popupimages').esgi();
});
```

only close button not work

Comment: you got a typo there? "class popupimage". vs $.'popupimageS') the class is without an s

Comment: tsm, still not wrking